# How get first line from Pandas and iterate columns values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe without headers. I want to read first line from dataframe then iterate all columns values to show user and suggest to set column name by value:

How to do that?

```
A B C 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

User must see:

```
1 ask to enter column name
2 ask to enter column name
3 ask to enter column name
```

Done.

I tried this:

```
for colindex in range(len(df.columns)):
    colvalue = df[colindex].values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

## Create a dataframe without columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame([*zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3])])
```

## iterate every column of the dataframe and save the first value of each column , ask for the input and rename dataframe column , finally print the dataframe to see the result

```
for column in df.columns[0:]:

   column_first_value=str(df[column][0])
   column_name = input(f'{column_first_value}\t Set column name: ')
   df = df.rename(columns = {column:column_name})




print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want user input - then you need the `input` function -

```py
user_col_names = []
for val in df.loc[0]:
    col_name = input(f'{val}\tEnter column name: ')
    user_col_names.append(col_name)
```

**Output**

```
1       Enter column name: a
2       Enter column name: b
3       Enter column name: c

# user_col_names                                                                                                                  
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Do note that ensuring these column names are valid is still up to you.